# SFMC journey builder custom activity headers format issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, custom-activity, header

I have created a custom journey builder activity type REST that can post to an external API successfully. However the external API requires a token for authentication that needs to be passed in the header of the request.

SFMC documentation here (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/rest.htm)  has a blank string for the headers and a url for the publish and save method headers. That makes absolutely no sense. Can somebody explain the format the headers should be in?

I am trying to pass "headers": [{"Authorization" : "Bearer theToken"}] via the json.config "execute" with no luck at all. I have tried the so many variations and no headers are passed to the API.

Any ideas?

Comment: What http response code are you getting?

Comment: I am receiving a 401 with message "Not Authorized" to all API endpoints that require an authorization header with a bearer token. I am receiving a 200 to all calls to REST API endpoints that do not require headers. 

When you look at the salesforce documentation here (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/rest.htm) they are asking for a URL as the headers. So in what format should the headers [{"Authorization" : "Bearer theToken",{''Content-Type";"application/json'}}] be in within the config.json to work?

Comment: Example snippet of headers within config.json -> arguments

Comment: "arguments": {
    "executionMode": "{{Context.ExecutionMode}}",
    "definitionId": "{{Context.DefinitionId}}",
    "activityId": "{{Activity.Id}}",
    "contactKey": "{{Context.ContactKey}}",
    "execute": {
      "inArguments": [],
      "outArguments": [],
      "url": "",
      "verb": "POST",
      "body": "",
   "headers": [{"Authorization":"Bearer xxxx"},{"Content-Type":"application/json"}],
      "format": "json",
      "useJwt": false,
      "timeout": 10000
    }

Comment: What is the correct format for headers to pass through my  Authorization header?

Comment: I installed the Postman like journey builder activity from https://www.sfmc-postman.com/. Its a really powerful and essential tool to have. I have been able to make custom API request in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journey builder. 
It works exactly the same as postman.
I can also create templates, environment variables and use response variables in my journey. Their analytics is also great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reached to the Marketing cloud team on this.

The custom headers are supported but for an access token, there is a bug that will be patched in the next release.

The release schedule (safe harbor) is below

> R0 is 3/22 2021, R1 is 4/10 2021, and R2 is 4/17 2021

Once it is fixed, the below will work fine

```
arguments": {
    "execute": {
        "inArguments": [
            {
                "emailAddress": "{{InteractionDefaults.Email}}"
            },
            {
                "phoneNumber": "{{Contact.Default.PhoneNumber}}"
            }
        ],
        "outArguments": [
            {
                "foundSignupDate": ""
            }
        ],
        "url": "https://some-endpoint.com/execute",
        "headers": "{\"Authorization\":\"Bearer theToken\"}" 
    }
```

Comment: ​@Mohith Shrivastava  thank you for the help. I ended up creating a micro-service that requires no headers to accept the call then relay it onto a specified REST service and attaching the required headers within my micro-service and returning the data back to the custom journey activity. This is working well.

Comment: I think I picked up another bug with the custom activities on the outArguments. I successfully retrieve outArguments from my REST activity within the journey and can use decision splits on them however when I try and use outArgument within another custom REST activity in the format {{Interaction.REST-1.access_token}} then the journey cannot activate and throws an error. Can you confirm if I can use outArguments within another REST activity and within an Update Contact activity if my format is correct {{Interaction.REST-1.access_token}}?

Comment: Good workaround for now! In April once it is fixed you can eat rid of the api call to attach the header!

Comment: @Edwin Jeppe To help others can you post this as another query here? I can talk to marketing cloud engineers and see what they say

Comment: I do not think I will be able to get rid of the middle layer api call. As I also saw that the custom journey activity passes additional data along with the REST call and not only the BODY part of the json.config and the 3rd party API rejects the call because it does not allow the additional attributes automatically appended. 
The values: inArguments;
 outArguments;
 activityObjectID;
 journeyId;
 activityId;
 definitionInstanceId;
 activityInstanceId;
 keyValue;
 mode;

Comment: I will post an additional query for the Update Contact activity issue

Comment: I installed the Postman like journey builder activity from https://www.sfmc-postman.com/. Its a really powerful and essential tool to have. I have been able to make custom API request in Salesforce Marketing Cloud Journey builder. 
It works exactly the same as postman.
I can also create templates, environment variables and use response variables in my journey. Their analytics is also great.